# Setting attributes using Rails + jQuery Tokeninput (Railscasts #258)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the jQuery Tokeninput plugin to set attributes for a virtual attribute (using fields_for). **I have no problem setting the attribute without the plugin activated**, but when Tokeninput is activated it does not pass the attributes of the content. The plugin is otherwise working properly (populating the tokens).

Any ideas why the content is empty when the plugin is active?

Here is my model:

```
class Fact
 include Mongoid::Document
 field :description, :type => String
 belongs_to :matter
 has_and_belongs_to_many :issues
 attr_reader :issue_contents
 attr_writer :issue_contents
 attr_writer :issue_matter_id
 after_save :assign_issues
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :issues

 def issue_contents
  @issue_contents ||= issues.map(&:content).join(', ')
 end

private

def assign_issues
 @issue_contents ||= issues.map(&:content).join(', ')
  if @issue.blank?
   @issue  = issues[0]
   @issue.destroy
end

if @issue_contents
  self.issues = @issue_contents.split(",").map do |content|
    matter.issues.find_or_create_by(content: (content))          
   end  
  end
```

Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@fact, :url => matter_facts_path(@fact.matter)) do |f| %>
...
<div class="clearfix">
 <%= f.label :add_fact %>
 <div class="input"><%= f.text_area(:description, :size=>"20x3") %></div>
</div>
<%= f.fields_for :issues do |x| %>
<div class="clearfix">
 <%= x.label :content %>
 <div class="input"><%= x.text_field :content, :id => "issue_content" %></div>
...
```

And the JS:

```
$(function () { 
 var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
 $('#issue_content').tokenInput(pathname + "/issues.json", 
{ crossDomain: false, propertyToSearch: "content", theme: 'facebook' });
```

Thanks!

Comment: I figured out the problem. The plugin sets the default tokenValue to: "id". I needed to change it to: "content".

Comment: @Scott I know this is old but if you solved the problem, can you post it as an answer and accept it?  Then it will be obvious that this was solved.